# Text format dropdown has dissapeared from edit article form

Tags: forms, input-formats

There is something strange it happened at a certain time. I no longer can set the text format from article (node) edit because the Text format input has dissapeared.

I can configure them from Configuration page but no longer can choose them from edit mode.

I have all permissions over them set up ok.

Please if you have any suggestions help me up.

[image]

Strangely, this combo dissapeared from admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE/fields/body as well

I tried to alter the content type filter using a module but no luck:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 

 $form['body']['und']['0']['#format'] = "full_html";

}
```

Comment: This normally happens when there is just an input format, or the user is allowed to use just an input format. Can you verify that is not the case?

Comment: No, there all 3 in place. Still not appears when I activate PHP input filter.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this issue when a rich-text editor is enabled. In my experience, the input format box reappears when the rich-text editor is disabled.